# Query from database on onChange event inside select input in React, Redux-Form and GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, redux-form, react-apollo

I'm trying to query from database when user select a machine from a `select input` field (which data is also coming from database). I'm using redux-form. My code is like below:

```js
<div className='universal_form-input'>
  <label>Mechine Name</label>
    <Field
      type='number'
      name='machine'
      component={this.renderSelect}
     />
</div>
```

And the `select input` filled with Machine name and `value` is the `id` of the corresponding Machine. Now when user will select a machine it state will be updated with the `id` value of that machine.

On `handleChange` I'm trying to invoke a method named `queryMachineById` which should fetch data by specific `machine id`. And the query should return `noOfDispenser` of that machine from database. (BTW this query is working on GraphQL playground)

```js
handleChange = (event, input) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    input.onChange(value);
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.queryMachineById();
    }, 1000);
  };
```

`queryMachineById` method is written like below:

```js
 queryMachineById = () => {
    const machineId = parseInt(this.state.machine);
    console.log(typeof machineId, machineId);
    return (
      <Query query={MACHINE_BY_ID_QUERY} variables={{ machineId }}>
        {({ data, loading, error }) => {
          if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
          if (error) return <p>Error</p>;
          console.log(data);
          return data.machineById.map(
            machine => (initialValues.dispenserNo = machine.noOfDispensers)
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  };
```

`machineId` is also updating with valid `id` from state. But the `console.log(data)` inside the `queryMachineById` is not showing anything, not even empty `{}`

My `GraphQL query` looks like this:

```
export const MACHINE_BY_ID_QUERY = gql`
  query MACHINE_BY_ID_QUERY($machineId: Int!) {
    machineById(machineId: $machineId) {
      id
      noOfDispensers
    }
  }
`;
```

`onClick` is also not working.

Comment: raact basic - you can't render from event handlers  ... hint: 'query on click'

Comment: I've never built this type of application before. And the functionality I'm trying to add never done it before. Nobody can be expert without asking dumb question and making silly mistakes. By disliking the question without proper explanation you are discouraging of asking silly questions. Now I'll think twice before asking for help. From where I'm asking question there isn't so many people to ask help for regarding these kind of topic. I believe this platform was build to help developers each other not discouraging them.

Answer (score 1):

### Outdated / deprecated

- using `<Query />` and `<Mutation/>` components is a sign of using outdated examples/tutorials/knowledge.

These days you should use `useLazyQuery` hook.

Of course **you can still use `<Query/>` component** or even older methods (`compose` [multiple] `graphql` HOCs) as long they are supported.

- Use [old docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/essentials/queries/#manually-firing-a-query)
- or you can use `skip` property to manually firing it ...
- or even [simpler] render `<Query/>` component conditionally.

Newer methods are described [in docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually).

### Bads

In React, **you can't render components from event handlers**. You can use methods [passed as props] derived from components (f.e. from [mutation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/essentials/mutations/#the-mutation-component)) but `never rendered from handler!` - like you can't return anything visible (to be rendered) from event handler (update state instead, render something conditionally) ... it's all **data driven**, `update data > render will update a view`.

---

**Update**

Component works only in render context/flow - event handler flow is separate, you can't use (as not rendering it) or return component to be rendered (rendering was finished earlier) - this way you can't use it's functionality - querying in this case.

[One of options] You have to render `<Query />` component in render flow and use `skip` property to block it's automatic firing at start. Handler can change blocking (`skip`) condition (use `setState`) and it will be fired and rerendered with `data` results. This way you have querying event driven.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and I'll update my query and mutation to the latest version. Actually I didn't fully understand what you said about the render bit. Can you please further clarify what I can do in my case here?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'm using `useLazyQuery` for querying data `onClick`. I've solved the problem by taking another route. I completely restructured my project.